# Beginning Java : passing to a constructor thru event listener

Tags: java, constructor, event-listener

So, what I want to accomplish is sending the GUI Data over to the constructor to set some new instances. But I'm not really too sure on how to accomplish this. I honestly don't even know if what I'm doing is allowed or not, but man it'd be easy if it just worked this way.

I have a GUI set up as you can see. Then when a user clicks on display, I want the program to collect the data. Then send it to the constructor.

Now, this is a school project, so I can't really ask for a full answer (code), but hopefully someone can help me better understand what I'm doing wrong. The compiler error I get is -return type invalid- but I know that the return types match up... o-o;

I'll provide any other info you need. If I can spruce this code up a bit to make it easier on the compiler, as if I'm doing the whole constructor thing wrong, lemme know. I'd like to have better habits while coding anyways.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Project2 extends JFrame {

//Instance Variables
private String sid;
private double length;
private boolean widths;
private String service;


//Declaring GUI Components
private JTextField jtfSSID;
private JTextField jtfLength;
private JTextArea jtaToString;
private JLabel jlblTitle;
private JLabel jlblSSID;
private JLabel jlblLength;
private JLabel jlblToString;
private JButton jbtDisplay;
private JButton jbtClear;
private JRadioButton jrbServiceStand;
private JRadioButton jrbServiceSuper;
private JRadioButton jrbServiceDelux;
private ButtonGroup bgService;
private JCheckBox jcbWStand;
private JCheckBox jcbWExtra;

private JPanel tpanel;
private JPanel ipanel;
private JPanel wpanel;
private JPanel spanel;
private JPanel opanel;

private final int WIDTH = 500;
private final int HEIGHT = 200;

//main method for inst and cust frame
public static void main(String[] args){
    Project2 frame = new Project2();
}

//Constructors + GUI constructs
public Project2(){
    setTitle("Project 2 : Bahia Mar Marina");
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setLocation(300, 200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    buildTitle();
    buildIdentity();
    buildWidth();
    buildService();
    buildOutput();
    add( tpanel, BorderLayout.NORTH );
    add( ipanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add( wpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER );
    add( spanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    add( opanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
    setVisible(true);
}

public Project2(String newSid, double newLength, boolean newWidths, String newService){
    setSid(newSid);
    setLength(newLength);
    isWidths(newWidths);
    setService(newService);
    }

    //-----------------------------setters
    public void setSid(String newSid){
        sid = newSid;
    }
    public void setLength(double newLength){
        if (length <= 20 && length >= 60 || length == 0) {
            length = newLength;
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Length! Between 20 - 60 please! Or 0 as a placeholder.");
        }
    }
    public void isWidths(boolean newWidths){
        widths = newWidths;
    }
    public void setService(String newService){
            service = newService;
    }

    //-----------------------------------getters
    public String getSid(){
        return sid;
    }
    public double getLength(){
        return length;
    }
    public boolean getWidths(){
        return widths;
    }
    public String getService(){
        return service;
    }

    //---------------------------------------to string
    public String toString( ){
        String output = "Slip ID: " + sid + " length of " + length + "ft. Wide: " + widths + ".\n-----Service Type: " + service;
        return output;
    }
//build top title
private void buildTitle(){
    tpanel = new JPanel();
    jlblTitle = new JLabel("Bahia Mar Marina");    
    tpanel.add(jlblTitle);



}
//build left ID
private void buildIdentity(){
    ipanel = new JPanel();
    ipanel.setLayout(new GridLayout (2,1));
    jlblSSID = new JLabel("SSID: ");
    jlblLength = new JLabel("Length: ");
    jtfSSID = new JTextField(4);
    jtfLength = new JTextField(4);

    ipanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Identity:"));
    ipanel.add(jlblSSID);
    ipanel.add(jtfSSID);
    ipanel.add(jlblLength);
    ipanel.add(jtfLength);


}
//build center width
private void buildWidth(){
    wpanel = new JPanel();
    wpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout (1,2));
    jcbWStand = new JCheckBox("Standard");
    jcbWExtra = new JCheckBox("Extra-wide");
    wpanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Width:"));
    wpanel.add(jcbWStand);
    wpanel.add(jcbWExtra);
}
//build left service
private void buildService(){
    spanel = new JPanel();
    spanel.setLayout(new GridLayout (3,1));
    jrbServiceStand = new JRadioButton("Standard");
    jrbServiceSuper = new JRadioButton("Superior");
    jrbServiceDelux = new JRadioButton("Deluxe");
    bgService = new ButtonGroup();
    bgService.add(jrbServiceStand);
    bgService.add(jrbServiceSuper);
    bgService.add(jrbServiceDelux);
    spanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Service:"));
    spanel.add(jrbServiceStand);
    spanel.add(jrbServiceSuper);
    spanel.add(jrbServiceDelux);

}
//build bottom output and buttons
private void buildOutput(){
    opanel = new JPanel();
    opanel.setLayout(new GridLayout (2,1));
    jlblToString = new JLabel("Data Output:");

    jtaToString = new JTextArea(2,16);
    jbtDisplay = new JButton("Display!");
    jbtDisplay.addActionListener(new DisplayButtonListener()); 
    jbtClear = new JButton("-Clear-");
    jbtClear.addActionListener(new ClearButtonListener()); 

    opanel.add(jbtDisplay);
    opanel.add(jbtClear);
    opanel.add(jlblToString);
    opanel.add(jtaToString);


}
//Display Listener
private class DisplayButtonListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
        sid = jtfSSID.getText();
        length = Double.parseDouble(jtfLength.getText());
        //service
        if(jrbServiceStand.isSelected()){
            service = "Standard";}
        else if(jrbServiceSuper.isSelected()){
            service = "Superior";}
        else if(jrbServiceDelux.isSelected()){
            service = "Deluxe";}
        //widths
        if(jcbWStand.isSelected()){
            widths = false;
        }
        if(jcbWExtra.isSelected()){
            widths = true;
        }

        Project2(sid, length, widths, service); 
    }

}
//Clear Listener
private class ClearButtonListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        jtfSSID.setText(" ");
        bgService.clearSelection();
        jtfLength.setText(" ");
        jcbWStand.setSelected(false);
        jcbWExtra.setSelected(false);


    }
}}
```

So, just to be specific and make sure... Here's the code with the error:

```
//Display Listener
private class DisplayButtonListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
        sid = jtfSSID.getText();
        length = Double.parseDouble(jtfLength.getText());
        //service
        if(jrbServiceStand.isSelected()){
        service = "Standard";}
        else if(jrbServiceSuper.isSelected()){
        service = "Superior";}
        else if(jrbServiceDelux.isSelected()){
        service = "Deluxe";}
        //widths
        if(jcbWStand.isSelected()){
        widths = false;
        }
        if(jcbWExtra.isSelected()){
        widths = true;
    }

    Project2(sid, length, widths, service); //THIS LINE HAS THE ERROR
}
```

and I want to pass it to:

```
public Project2(String newSid, double newLength, boolean newWidths, String newService){
    setSid(newSid);
    setLength(newLength);
    isWidths(newWidths);
    setService(newService);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line makes no sense:

```
Project2(sid, length, widths, service);
```

If you want to pass the information to a new class via a constructor, then sure, do it, but to call a constructor you need to proceed the class name with the `new` keyword, and you don't want to call this same class but rather a different one, right?  Something like:

```
MydisplayDialog displayDialog = new MydisplayDialog(this, sid, length, 
    widths, service);
displayDialog.setVisible(true);
```

Where MydisplayDialog is a new class, possibly a JDialog, that displays the information that you've just collected.

Comment: Ah wow. Okay. That makes sense. Though, I don't want it to display in a new window, but rather toString to a text field area. :o But I see what you're saying. So, possibly...

`Project2 newBoatSlip = new Project2(sid, length, widths, service);
 jtaToString.setText(ToString());`

Comment: @Daniel:  if all you want to do is display it in a JTextArea, then either pass a String into the JTextArea via its `setText(...)` method, or append a String to the JTextArea via its `append(...)` method.  Don't try to create a new Project2 object or call its constructor. Again, that makes no sense. By the way, you should have mentioned wanting to display things in the JTextArea in your original question. No sense in making us guess these things.

Comment: I don't know if I can do that. I should have been more descriptive with the instructions of the project. :/ 

`It should use that information to create a boat slip object.  It should then call the toString() method from your boat slip class and display its output back to the user in the JTextArea.  Your output should fit neatly within the JTextArea and should be easy to read without words running together or breaking midline. In order to receive full credit, you MUST create instances of your classes and call methods to produce your output that will be displayed in your GUI.`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to use a constructor... you want to call a method inside of Project2, right?  You're not creating a new Project2, is that correct?

I wouldn't create a whole new class for the listener.  I would do something like:

```
public void newMethod(String newSid, double newLength, boolean newWidths, String newService){
    setSid(newSid);
    setLength(newLength);
    isWidths(newWidths);
    setService(newService);
}
```

and then for your listener, I would create an anonymous listener:

```
jbtDisplay.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                // do your stuff
                newMethod(sid, length, widths, service);
            }
        }
```

EDIT:

Based on your comments on another answer, you do want a second object.  The problem, then, is more fundamental.  You are trying to combine your GUI with your object.  You need to have separate classes handle your JFrame and your application logic.

Comment: Okay. So I solved it by:

`Project2 newBoatSlip = new Project2(sid, length, widths, service);
   jtaToString.setText(""+newBoatSlip.toString());`

Comment: @Daniel'Dige'Force: You may have gotten it to run, but it's not written well.  It's not using objects the way they were intended to be used. Hovercraft:  Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel: your solution is wrong. Period. You need to create a new class, a BoatSlip class, that is not the same as your GUI class, that has a decent toString method. You most certainly should not create a new Project2 object if you want to solve this project correctly. You should also up-vote Danation's answer as it is quite helpful to you.